# How are expression objects (EXPRSXP) used in R?

Tags: r

I was wondering how expression objects (EXPRSXP) are used in R? It seems to me that R almost always using call objects to carry out the language computation. Any one could point to me some places that expression objects are used instead of call objects?

Another side question... for three points in a promise, does the third pointer pointing to an call object (LANGSXP) or an expression object (EXPRSXP)?

Thanks,
Shen

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return value of `parse` is an expression, so this would be a common use case for expressions (I've used expressions a fair bit in this type of context).

```
str(parse(text="1 + 1\n2+2"))
# length 2 expression(1 + 1, 2 + 2)
```

Promises are documented as [containing expressions](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Promise-objects), though in most cases presumably they would be 1 length expressions, so effectively a call/symbol, though probably still stored as an expression (I'm speculating here).

Comment: Thank you!! Just a quick follow up question: I was wondering what are some uses of "parse". I thought what R does is to quote first to get an call object, then evaluate the object recursively? what are some usages of a parsed result?

Comment: @Shen parsing is the process of converting text into a series of calls.  The main purpose of parsing is to convert a file containing R code into a series of calls that R can then evaluate.  So, the workflow for the `source` command is basically R File -> parse -> quoted calls -> eval -> results of evaluated calls.  Note `parse(text="1 + 1")[[1]]` === `quote(1 + 1)`